# java 8: remove element from list if its not found in map key

Tags: java, list, java-8, hashmap

I would like to remove all list elements, which their last split char not founded as a key in some map. I use following code:

```
   List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("a.b.c,c.d.e".split(","));
   myList.add("a.b.c");
   Map myMap = new HashMap();
   myMap.put("a","dumy");
   myList.removeIf(el->!myMap.containsKey(el.substring(el.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)));
```

I get following error: `Method threw 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException' exception`.

any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Can you add the code that produces this error? These types have spelling errors etc.

Comment: the last code line cuses the error. i have updated the code

Comment: Your code is working fine. I assuming that you are showing us the wrong code and in actual code, you are using something like `Arrays.asList()` or immutable list.

Comment: @ByeBye Aside `Arrays.asList` is not immutable. But yes, in general, the operation to remove an element from an immutable collection might cause `UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: Well I build the list as followes: List<String> myList=Arrays.asList(cats.split(","));. Is this the reason for that error? how to solve it ?

Comment: @user1167753 Unless you share the complete context, no one would be able to provide a solution to it. Please edit the question and update with a minimal reproducible example for the problem.

Comment: code updated. first line seems to cuse the issue. why and how to solve it? THANKS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Arrays.asList()` creates fixed-size list. You cannot add new elements or remove elements.

You can use `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(el))`

Answer (score 1):

To further explain a bit the reason behind why adding (and deleting) from an `ArrayList` created through `Arrays.asList (array)` is not permitted and throws `UnsupportedOperationException`, first we know that what this `Arrays.asList(...)` does is to convert an array to its equivalent instance of `ArrayList`:

```
String[] strArr = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(strArr);
```

What's happening here is your `strArr` is actually a backing array for `strList`, meaning if you modify `strArr[0]` then the value at `strList.get(0)` will also follow suit, and vice versa.  Yes, their values will sync and will remain consistent to each other.  This is why you cannot do an addition or deletion for `strList` because the backing array will cry and panic as it cannot fulfill it as it is fixed-length (arrays are always fixed size as we know, if you need to resize an array, you need to create a whole new array altogether, resize an existing one is not possible); thus it throws `UnsupportedOperationException`.

So the solution, as already mentioned by @ByeBye, is to wrap it with an `ArrayList` so it would be a new independent `ArrayList` with no backing array whatsoever and has freedom to do addition and deletion.

Answer (score -1):

solved by adjusting code line as followes:

```
List<String> myList = Lists.newArrayList(Arrays.asList("a.b.c,c.d.e".split(",")));
```